# Sensor Fusion of Two Same Type of Data

Tags: filters, estimation, kalman-filters, sensor, bayesian-estimation

I have an object moving with sinusoidal motion. I estimate the position of the object using lidar and camera separately. Then I want to fuse these two estimation data in the optimal way. For example I apply Kalman filtering to lidar data and I get estimated position and variance. This same process can be applied to camera data. I fuse these two using Weighted Average or Kalman Filters with Multiple Update Steps (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813719/multi-sensors-fusion-using-kalman-filter)). This method can apply different kalman filter type as extended kalman filter, particle filter etc.

How can I apply different fusing methods or filtering methods to combine sensor data in a suitable way?

Comment: What's the motivation for a different way? If the assumptions of Kalman filter hold in your case, stick with it.

Comment: I want to compare between diffrent methods and I want to make a performance comparison between them.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85434/kalman-filter-on-sensor-fusion